# JAX-RS variable path depth

Tags: java, jax-rs

Is it possible to get a variable amount of path depth?

Paths example:

- `https://www.example.com/rest/images/part1/part2/part3/image.jpg`
- `https://www.example.com/rest/images/part1/part2/image.jpg`
- `https://www.example.com/rest/images/part1/image.jpg`

Code example:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/image")
@Produces("image/*")
@Consumes("image/*")
public class ImageResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/{image}")
    public Response getImage(@PathParam("image") String image) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I mainly use two Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Maybe use urlencoded `@QueryParam` to submit the whole (variable part) of the image path? E.g. "images/image?path=/part1/part2/part3/image.jpg” with `@QueryParam("path") path`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the information to be in the url path (your example code seems to simply want to put the image-path into a string), you could get the desired information by using a `@QueryParam`:

```
@GET
@Path("/image")
public Response getImage(@QueryParam("imagepath") String image) {
    ...
}
```

Call the endpoint via ".../images/image?imagepath=...". Also, I did not test it and you might have to escape your forward slashes (maybe `%2F` or use `URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")` on client side).

If however I misunderstood your use case and you really want variable paths, that is not possible afaik. In that case, maybe you should use one endpoint per part.